# Visual Studio does not recognize NgRx ofType() return type (showing never type, still compiles and runs well in browser)

Tags: angular, visual-studio, typescript, ngrx, visual-studio-2019

I have the following code which uses NgRx `Effect`:

[image]

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Actions, ofType, Effect } from "@ngrx/effects";
import { SearchContactService } from "../../search-contact.service";
import { Action } from "@ngrx/store";
import { Observable, of } from "rxjs";
import { SearchActionTypes, SearchTagResultAction, SearchKeywordResultAction } from "../actions/search.action";
import { mergeMap, map, debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, filter } from "rxjs/operators";

@Injectable()
export class SearchEffects {

    @Effect()
    enterSearch$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(SearchActionTypes.SearchEnterKeyword),
        filter(action => { return action && action.payload.keyword && action.payload.keyword.length }),
        debounceTime(300),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        mergeMap(action => {
            let keyword = action.payload.keyword as string;

            if (keyword.startsWith("#")) {
                return this.searchContactService.searchTag(keyword.substr(1))
                    .pipe(
                        map(data => new SearchTagResultAction({
                            tags: data,
                        }))
                    );
            } else {
                return this.searchContactService.searchContact(keyword)
                    .pipe(
                        map(data => new SearchKeywordResultAction({
                            contacts: data,
                        }))
                    );
            }
        }),
    );

    constructor(
        private searchContactService: SearchContactService,
        private actions$: Actions) {

    }

}
```

The code compiles and runs well in browser. However, it's quite annoying that VS shows the error at every `action` parameter.

Anyone has this problem? How can I solve it?

EDIT: I found out it is because of `ofType` method, not the `pipe` itself. Still cannot understand why yet.

EDIT 2: After adding type for `ofType` another assignment error. In browser, it still compiles and runs. I even tried `SearchActions` (my union Action type), same problem still.

[image]

EDIT: Found out the solution: use explicit type on mergeMap too:

```
mergeMap<SearchEnterKeywordAction, SearchActions>(action => {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to type the `ofType` operator:

```
ofType<SearchEnterKeyword>(SearchActionTypes.SearchEnterKeyword),
```

Since NgRx 7 you can also type the `Actions` injected by `@ngrx/effects`

```
constructor(private actions$: Actions<MyActionsUnion>) {}
```

Comment: Thanks that work for the unknown type. Could you please explain the latter part? What is it? On VS, I still get a compiler error message (going to update my post to add screenshot) at `mergeMap` though (another error, not `never` type). The code still compiles and runs, only VS complains.